# Make a button "italic"

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working an a off canvas menu and I want to make the button stripes be kind of itallic like on this website:
http://moombahteam.nl/

The code i've got is:

```
/* Menu Button */
.menu-button {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
margin: 1em;
padding: 0;
width: 2.5em;
height: 2.25em;
border: none;
text-indent: 2.5em;
font-size: 1.5em;
color: transparent;
background: transparent;
color:black;
font-style: italic;
}

.menu-button::before {  
position: absolute;
top: 0.5em;
right: 0.5em;
bottom: 0.5em;
left: 0.5em;
background: linear-gradient(#373a47 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 40%, #373a47 40%, #373a47 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 80%, #373a47 80%);
content: '';
}

.menu-button:hover {
opacity: 0.6;
}
```

The button code is

```
<button class="menu-button" id="open-button"></button>
```

I've got all the elements and I've got it working. I just don't know how to do the lines.

Help will be greatly accepted!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using background gradient to create the burger icon, you can use for example `transform: skew(-15deg);` on the `before` element to achieve this effect

Answer (score 0):

In the case of that web, they use FontAwesome icons:

```
.slideout-toggle a:before {
content: "\f0c9";
font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

[Here](http://fontawesome.io/icon/bars/) is the icon that they use.